# Floating Action Bar in android with maven

Tags: android, maven, floating-action-button

I am developing one feature with Floating Action Bar(FAB) in android. My project is in Maven and my device is on Android lolipop. Can anyone suggest me how to use FAB with maven in Android lolipop?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, which you should.
Simply add the design support library to your android project's `build.gradle` 
`compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'`

If maven is your requirement, then you can add a `floatingactionbutton` to your project by adding the lines below into your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.getbase/floatingactionbutton -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.getbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>floatingactionbutton</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The library used will be : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.getbase/floatingactionbutton/1.9.0

Comment: My project is in maven and the requirement is also for maven. I can't export from maven to gradle. So how do i use in maven?

Comment: @user3076440 Edited my answer